# Laravel ONLY on Live Server Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server, routes

I'm getting this error overnight, despite I haven't updated any file.
The website has been working perfectly fine for 3 weeks and I am suddenly 
getting this error when trying to submit anything through POST method.
I'm hosting two laravel-based websites and it's happening in both of them.
Any idea would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure there are no redirects on the server, such as HTTP -> HTTPS.

Comment: Did you implemented any changes before? Maybe you can check if there is a cache active so the routes in your routes file are not the ones actually used. Try ```php artisan route:clear```. Also check, if there is another route defined before the expected one having another method but the same structure of the URI.

Comment: Thanks @Danaq, I haven't updated anything in a while. I don't really know how to run commands on the live server, should I connect throught gitbash or something like that?

Comment: Thanks @aynber, do you know where can I find that in my cpanel?

Comment: Not a clue for cPanel. I've seen redirects like that in an .htaccess file. You can verify what is happening by watching the Network tab of your browser's developer tools

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know if can use that, the simplest solution would be to connect via SSH to your live server. If you don't have access to your server via SSH you probably used FTP to publish your project. While this can work (i.e. deploying on a windows machine) it can also cause tricky problems.

I had a similar problem recently on a windows machine where one cannot simply execute an `artisan` command on the shell.

My solution was to set up a route and added this code in the controller method

```php
$output = new BufferedOutput;

Artisan::call('route:list', [], $output); // use route:clear instead

return dd($output->fetch());
```

You can try the same replacing `'route:list'` with `'route:clear'`.
Also maybe try to comment all other routes in your route file and try the one not working at the moment again.
If it is still failing, the problem comes from your server settings.
If this works, it has more presumably something to do with the arrangement of your routes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Danaq. I just run the "php artisan route:clear" command, but it didn't fix the issue. When I run "php artisan route:list" it identifies my POST routes properly, so I have no clue what's going on

Comment: Can you try to comment all routes except for the one not working and trying to send your request again?

Comment: Just tried that and got the same error. I'll take a look at htaccess files.. I have no clue what's going on this is so weird

Comment: You could also try to test the request without using the form in postman for example.

Comment: OK, just for checking really everything: Did you check if the from really says ```method="POST"```?

Comment: Danaq Thank you very much for your help. You won't believe what the issue was... It turns out I regularly upload a set of files every two days, and I hadn't had any issues so far. This time I couldn't make it work even after trying an infinite amount of fixes. After 5 hours I luckily ended up figuring out it was all caused by the fact that both of the PDF files I was given yesterday had a single quote character (') on their names. So that was it... Begginer mistakes I guess. I'll implement a "string cleaner" code line for my files names now. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

It was all caused by a single quote character (') in the PDF files I was trying to upload. 
**insert facepalm gif**